The functional equation $f(x+1) = \dfrac{z x + f(2x)}{x + 1}$
Let $x$ be real.
Consider this equation.
$f(\exp(x) +1) = \dfrac{f(2) \exp(x) + f(2 \exp(x))}{\exp(x) + 1}$
Apart from the trivial solutions $f(\exp(x)) = C$ for a constant $C$ independant of $x$, are there continu solutions ? Or piecewise continu solutions ?
Do we get contradictions ?
How about analytic solutions ? Or piecewise analytic solutions ?
Maybe this makes more sense ;
replace $\exp(x)$ with $x$.
(nevermind $x > 0$)
replace $f(2)$ with $z$ (and later solve for $z = f(2) $ )
Then we get for a given $z$ or parameter $z$ :
$$f(x+1) = \dfrac{z x + f(2x)}{x + 1}$$
for any $x$ not equal to $-1$ this makes sense. And $f(0)$ and $x = -1$ might make sense afterall as a pole or limit or such.
Assuming no contradictions can occur, I think we plug this in a taylor series and solve for the coefficients. Or a pade.

I got inspired by addition formulas as you probably guessed.

Adding to Lee's answer, there are also solutions that are not analytic at $y=2$. Define $y=x-1$ and $g(x)=f(x+2)$ to get
$$g(2y)=(y+2)g(y)-(y+1)g(0)$$
It is now clear that if we start with any function on $[1,2)$ we get a unique extension of the function on $(0,\infty)$. Furthermore, if $g(2)=g(1)=g(0)=0$ this will be continuous. Similarly, we can make the function $n$ times differentiable by requiring that it is $n$ times differentiable on $[1,2]$ and the $0$th to $n$th derivatives at $1$ and $2$ are all $0$. You can require the function to be smooth in this way, too, but of course they can never be analytic.
We can do exactly the same process for $y\le 0$, and because both sides have $g(0)=0$ we can join them together into a continuous function on $(-\infty,\infty)$. In fact, $g^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$, so we can join functions for $y\ge 0$ and $y\le 0$ to make smooth functions on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Say that $a_n = \tfrac{f^{(n)}(2)}{n!}$, and that $a_{-1} = 0$. We can rearrange your equation by multiplying both sides by $x+1$ and then make the substitution $y +1 = x$. We get:
$$(y+2)f(y+2) = z + zy+ f(2y+2)$$
Now we expand both left and right side as taylor series centered at $y = 2$.
$$(y+2)\sum_{n \geq 0}a_n y^n = z + zy + \sum_{n \geq 0}a_n 2^n y^n$$
Now define the sequence, $b_n = z, z, 0, 0, 0, \dots$ A little more algebra and we have that:
$$\sum_{n \geq 0} (a_{n-1} + 2a_n)y^n = \sum_{n \geq 0}(b_n + 2^na_n)y^n$$
Which yields the recurrence $a_{n-1} + 2a_n = b_n + 2^na_n$. This is a first order recurrence relation with initial condition $a_{-1} = 0$ and it should fully define the function in question.

You can see that as $n$ grows $a_n \approxeq 2^{-n}a_{n-1}$ this is a sequence which decreases very quickly, so there is a unique entire function which solves your functional equation. There may be other non continuous solutions but I'm not sure.

Yes this has MANY solutions. One of them is:
$$ f_{\infty}(u) = \frac{z}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[   \frac{2x + 2^{-n} - 2}{2^{-n}}  \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2}{\frac{2x + 2^{1-k} - 2}{2^{1-k}}+ 2} \right] $$
But finding it is a difficult dragon to slay so be prepared for a long fight.
Some Setup:
We consider the equation
$$ f(x+1) = \frac{zx + f(2x)}{x+1} $$
This is a linear equation involving 2 parts of $f$ and so therefore it will have at least two trivially generated solutions. We begin by re-arranging it to:
$$ (x+1)f(x+1) - f(2x) = zx $$
Then we divide by $(x+1)$ on both sides
$$ f(x+1) - \frac{1}{x+1} f(2x) = zx $$
We then make the substitution $x = \frac{u}{2}$ to yield
$$ f(\frac{u}{2} +1 )- \frac{1}{\frac{u}{2} +1} f(u) = \frac{zu}{2}  $$
And simplify our algebra bit
$$ f \left( \frac{u+2}{2} \right) - \frac{2}{u+2} f(u) = \frac{z}{2} u  $$
How to Solve Arbitrary 2-term linear functional equations:
Now we consider a slightly more general case. Suppose we have the linear functional equation equation of the form
$$ f(a(x)) + b(x)f(x) = c(x)  $$
We will call this $L[f] = c(x)$  where the $L$ is the operator short hand for $f(a(x)) + b(x)f(x)$.
We can start by asking "if we guessed the solution was $f_0(x) = c(a^{-1}(x))$ how bad of an answer would that be?"
And clearly it wouldn't be the worst.
$$L[f_0(x)] = L[c(a^{-1}(x))] = c(x)+  b(x) c(a^{-1}(x))$$.
We almost have the right answer here but we just have this extra error term of $  b(x) c(a^{-1}(x))$. So our next guess would be
$$ f_1(x) = c(a^{-1}(x)) -b(a^{-1}(x)) c(a^{-2}(x)) $$
Now we have that
$$L[f_1] = c(x) - b(x)b(a^{-1}(x))c(a^{-2}(x)) $$
Again we are only one term away, so we need to add a correction for this. Adding that correction gives us:
$$f_2(x) = c(a^{-1}(x)) -b(a^{-1}(x)) c(a^{-2}(x)) + b(a^{-1}(x))b(a^{-2}(x))c(a^{-3}(x))$$
If you check by hand however even this will leave just ONE extra term. We can repeat this process infinitely many times (I'm going to use $\cdot$ to mean multiplication and stop featuring the $x$ in the functions, you can fill them in with your head) to find:
$$ f_{\infty} = c(a^{-1}) -b(a^{-1}) \cdot c(a^{-2}) + b(a^{-1})\cdot b(a^{-2})\cdot c(a^{-3}) - b(a^{-1})\cdot b(a^{-2})\cdot b(a^{-3}) c(a^{-4}) ...  $$
And we see a pattern emerge here! It's a bit verbose to put into sigma notation but we can write it as $$ f_{\infty}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ (-1)^n c(a^{-(n+1)}(x)) \prod_{k=1}^{n} b\left( a^{-k}(x) \right) \right] $$
If this function converges for any $x$ in the complex plane then it MUST obey the functional equation you have. However it's not the only such function...
Instead of our starting guess being $f_0(x) = c(a^{-1}(x))$ we could have instead considered
$$f_0'(x) = \frac{c(x)}{b(x)}$$.
This too would not be such a bad guess because
$$ L[f_0'(x)] = \frac{c(a(x))}{b(a(x))} + c(x) = c(x) + \frac{c(a(x))}{b(a(x))} $$
Again, we are almost on the money here, we just have that extra term we need to get rid of. I'll cut to the chase. This too is an infinite series and it looks like:
$$ f_{\infty}' = \frac{c}{b} - \frac{c(a)}{b(a)b} + \frac{c(a^2)}{b(a^2)b(a)b} - \frac{c(a^3)}{b(a^3)b(a^2)b(a)b} ... $$
This can be expressed in sigma notation as:
$$ f_{\infty}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ (-1)^n \frac{c(a^k(x))}{ \prod_{k=0}^{n} b\left( a^{k}(x) \right)} \right] $$
Again if that converges at all for any choice of $x$ this gives rise to a non trivial solution as well. So our goal ultimately will be to compute either $f_{\infty}$ or $f_{\infty}'$ for your original functional equation.
Solving your problem:
So now we get to the main course. Recall again we wish to solve:
$$ f \left( \frac{u+2}{2} \right) - \frac{2}{u+2} f(u) = \frac{z}{2} u  $$
Therefore $a(u) = \frac{u+2}{2}$, $b(u) = - \frac{2}{u+2}$ and $c(u) =\frac{z}{2} u$
We need to find a closed form for $a^k(u)$. We know that
$$\begin{align} & a^0(u) =   u \\ 
& a(u) =  \frac{u+2}{2}\\ 
& a(a(u)) =  \frac{ \frac{u+2}{2}+2}{2} = \frac{u+2+2^2}{2^2} \\  
& a(a(a(u))) =  \frac{\frac{ \frac{u+2}{2}+2}{2}+2}{2} =\frac{\frac{u+2+2^2}{2^2} + 2}{2} = \frac{u+2+2^2+2^3}{2^3}  \end{align} \\  $$
At this point we can stare at this and use the pattern matching part of our brains to conclude $a^k(u) = \frac{u+2+2^2 +... 2^k}{2^k}$ And that simplifies to: $a^k(u) = \frac{u + 2^{k+1} - 2}{2^k}$
We now start with our first fundamental solution:
$$ f_{\infty}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ (-1)^n c(a^{-(n+1)}(x)) \prod_{k=1}^{n} b\left( a^{-k}(x) \right) \right] $$
We substitute and simplify a bit:
$$ f_{\infty}(u) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[  \frac{z}{2} \frac{u + 2^{-n} - 2}{2^{-n}}  \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2}{\frac{u + 2^{1-k} - 2}{2^{1-k}}+ 2} \right] $$
$$ f_{\infty}(u) = \frac{z}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[   \frac{u + 2^{-n} - 2}{2^{-n}}  \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2}{\frac{u + 2^{1-k} - 2}{2^{1-k}}+ 2} \right] $$
So does this thing converge? Well at first glance we see the $\frac{u + 2^{-n} - 2}{2^{-n}} $. As $n \rightarrow \infty$ this approaches $\frac{u-2}{0}$ and that clearly diverges.
But now we also have that product term:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2}{\frac{u + 2^{1-k} - 2}{2^{1-k}}+ 2}  $$
The highest order term in this product is: $\frac{2}{\frac{u + 2^{1-n} - 2}{2^{1-n}}+ 2} $ and that is very very small number because $\frac{u + 2^{1-n} - 2}{2^{1-n}}$ gets very big. In fact its in an obvious sense at worst only within a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ of completely dividing out and deleting our originally diverging $\frac{u + 2^{-n} - 2}{2^{-n}} $. But here's the best part. Thats the LAST term in the product. There are $(n-1)$ MORE terms we have. So yes this is very very very rapidly going to 0. And therefore:
$$ f_{\infty}(u) = \frac{z}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[   \frac{u + 2^{-n} - 2}{2^{-n}}  \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2}{\frac{u + 2^{1-k} - 2}{2^{1-k}}+ 2} \right] $$
Is a convergent solution to your equation. I don't even know if it is a continuous solution. But we have an algorithm above that will allow us to evaluate it. Great so we found one solution. How do we find all the solutions?
Generating All Solutions:
(I'll fill this out tomorrow after I finish my work).
TLDR: given a linear functional equation $L[f] = c$ you want to generate the fundamental solutions using the procedure I gave above. Then for any fundamental solution $q$, and for any solution $s$ to $L[f] = 0$ (these can always be found through some crazy shit involving cayley graphs)  $q+s$ is also a solution to $L[f] = c$. This is a generalization of the superposition principle from linear differential equations. In fact for any two solutions $m_1, m_2$ to $L[f] = c$ if $t_1, t_2$ are constants such that $t_1 + t_2 = 1$ then $t_1 m_1 + t_2 m_2$ is YET another valid solution.
But even THAT is not all. For any linear functional equation of the form $L[f] = f(a(x)) + b(x)f(x) = c(x)$ there exists a chain-rule so that $L[f(g(x))] = L_x[g]*O_f[g]$ where $O$ is another linear operator. Our $t_1, t_2$ above NEED not be constants but rather functions such that $O[t] = 0$.
Putting all this together generates almost all the solutions.
These ideas also readily generalize to beyond 2-terms although they can be quite tedious to use in practice.
